# How to apply lens profile to multiple photos in Lightroom 6

Tags: lightroom-6

Is it possible to apply lens profile correction to multiple photos?

I am using Lightroom 6.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Applying the same modification to many images is pretty much the core functionality of LR.

1. Select and modify one image to your liking, including lens profile correction.
2. Add all images to the selection that should get the same treatment.
3. Hit the sync button at the bottom of the basic panel and make sure
   that the lens profile correction is selected to be synced

Alternatively, there's a little switch to the left of the sync button, which allows you to enable auto-sync. See this image:
[image]

The difference between both syncs is that just hitting the sync button will take all the modifications from the "master" image and copy them over. If you change settings later, they will not be synced with the other images.
auto-sync keeps the settings in sync as you apply them to all the images selected.

Check these two websites explaining this in more detail:

- http://lightroomkillertips.com/lightroom-quick-tip-use-auto-sync/
- http://www.slrlounge.com/school/how-to-use-the-sync-and-auto-sync-functions-to-batch-process-images-in-lightroom-4/
  (the image above is from this one)

Comment: you can also rt click and choose 'Copy Settings', then check the box by "Lens Corrections". Select your images in Library, and then rt click, choosing 'Develop Settings', 'Paste Settings"